# how to create a view in mvc which populates list of questions from datebase table and add dropdownlist against each question?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

i'm creating a mvc5 application and want to create a template of questionnaire which have more than one section. i'm having problem with displaying questions from database and each question have four dropdown lists with predefined list items and a comments box . eventually, i want to create template for questionnaire using razor pages. any help will be appreciated so far i have tried so many thing but nothing worked for me what i have tried so far is:

```
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Attribute
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Quality Rate
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Availability
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Condition
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Evaluation
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Comment
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    @{
                        List<InspectionEvaluation> evaluationList = new List<InspectionEvaluation>();
                        using (adnocDBEntities entities = new adnocDBEntities())
                        {
                            var entranceQuestion = from q in entities.QUESTIONS
                                                   from l in entities.locations
                                                   where l.location_description == "Entrance"
                                                   select new
                                                   {
                                                       q.Question_ID,
                                                       q.Question_description,
                                                       l.location_id
                                                   };
                            foreach (var obj in entranceQuestion)
                            {
                                InspectionEvaluation instance = new InspectionEvaluation();
                                instance.location_id = obj.location_id;
                                instance.question_id = obj.Question_ID;
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(obj.Question_description, new { @class = "form-control" })

                                    </td>
                                    <td class="form-group">
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(instance.QualityRate, new List<SelectListItem>
                                   {
                                       new SelectListItem { Text = "Male", Value="Male" },
                                       new SelectListItem { Text = "Female", Value="Female" }
                                   }, "Select Quality Rate",new {@class="form-control dropdown-menu" })
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(instance.Avaliability, new List<SelectListItem>
                                   {
                                       new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value="Yes" },
                                       new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value="No" }
                                   }, "Select Availability",new {@class="form-control dropdown-menu" })
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(instance.Condition, new List<SelectListItem>
                                   {
                                       new SelectListItem { Text = "New", Value="New" },
                                       new SelectListItem { Text = "Old", Value="Old" }
                                   }, "Select Condition",new {@class="form-control dropdown-menu" })
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(instance.Evaluation, new List<SelectListItem>
                                  {
                                      new SelectListItem { Text = "Replace", Value="Replace" },
                                      new SelectListItem { Text = "Required", Value="Required" },
                                      new SelectListItem { Text = "Recommend", Value="Recommend" }
                                  }, "Select Evaluation",new {@class="form-control dropdown-menu" })
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(instance.Comment, new { @class = "form-control", @Style = "border-radius:20px;" })

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                evaluationList.Add(instance);
                            }




                        }
                    }


                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Side note: `@Html.TextBoxFor(instance.Comment, new { @class = "form-control", @Style = "border-radius:20px;" })` seem not correct, did you mean `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => instance.Comment, new { @class = "form-control", @Style = "border-radius:20px;" })`? Also your DropDownListFor helper should use lambda too.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto thank for response i have solved it myself the dropdown is not showing because of bootstrap class dropdown-menu i have changed it to dropdown it worked for me